# USB-Installer doesn't boot

Tags: release-juno, system-installation

I tried to install elementary OS today on my tower but I ran into a problem. I installed a previous version of Juno without problems, but now I can't get the Installer to boot.

I downloaded the Installer and checked the checksum, it was correct. Then I flashed the USB with etcher and tried to boot it. During the reboot I selected the USB and tried all three option (try, install and OEM install) but I got the same result every time: The screens show a weird pattern and then goes blank. Then the fans of the graphic cars spins up to max for a moment before they slow down again and I'm stuck with a black screen.

I'm running the following hardware:

- AMD fx8350
- Asus Sabertooth 990fx
- AMD RX 590

Thank you very much in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Same here, but I tried on the same hardware system like before the same elementary OS image on a USB stick. I think it is the same, because I tried to download the new one, but the  torrent client verified that it is the same like an year ago. What I found is that if I try to boot with the same USB stick another computer, everything is ok.

The only way to start the current one was by using **nomodeset** parameter before I choose the 'try' option. To achieve this select 'Try elementary OS' and press the 'e' key on the keyboard, then add nomodeset after `quiet splash` so it became `quiet splash nomodeset ---` and press Ctrl+x to boot the system with this parameter. Good luck!

Comment: some information about nomodeset, quiet and splash - https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean

Comment: I tried your solution but sadly still got the same weird pattern and the blackscreen afterwards. I also tried the Installer on an old laptop, it worked normal.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. nomodeset has to be with lower case. Can you try like that? I edit my answer..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it with lower case again and the live system boots but during boot i get a driver error for the GPU and the live System runs on low resolution. I will try an install tomorrow to see, if this or a driver will fix this last issue.

Comment: I tried the installation and the error continued. Sadly I wasn't able to install the ubuntu driver for my graphics card after installation so I can't run elementary at the moment. After the installation I did some testing with other linux distributions and discovered, that older kernel version don't support the RX 590 (for example OpenSuse with Kernel Version 4.12). Is there a way to upgrade the Kerne to a newer one because it seems to be finde on 5.X?

Comment: I don't have any experience with AMD graphic cards.. For Nvidia there is a reository with Proprietary GPU Drivers, but I do not know one for Radeon. Probably you have to ask a new question here, hope somebody have information. About the newer kernel, I did this before with elementary OS Loki and I had a lot of problems, probably because the eOS team does not implemented any pathces to the os for the newer kernels.